# Django author Form not saving to database

Tags: python-3.x, django

models.py

```py
    class Blog(models.Model):
       title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
       slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
       post_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to ='media/post_pics/', default =None )
       body = models.TextField()
       posted = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
       #author = must be logged in, populate from login details
```

forms.py

```py
    class postForm(forms.Form):
       title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
       slug = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
       post_pic = forms.ImageField()
       body = forms.CharField(widget=SummernoteWidget())
```

views.py

```py
    def write_detail(request):
        template_name = 'blog/write.html'
        
        if request.method == 'POST':

            post_form = postForm(request.POST)
            
            if post_form.is_valid():
                new_post = Blog(title=title,slug=slug,post_pic=post_pic,body=body)
                new_post.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(blog.get_absolute_url()) 

        else:
            post_form = postForm()
     
        return render(request, template_name, {'post_form': post_form})
```

write.html

```html
    {% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    {% block back-img %}'{% static 'blog/assets/img/intro.jpg' %}'{% endblock back-img %}
     {% block titdes %}Write{% endblock titdes %}
     {% block title %}Write{% endblock title %}
     {% block pagedes %}A django powered community blog{% endblock pagedes %}
    {% block body%}

    <form method = "POST">
    {{ post_form.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Publish</button>
    </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

I have set up this form so that authors can write articles to the blog without accessing the admin panel and I believe it should work but it isn't saving to the database.

I have tried to work on the views over and over but don't know what else to do. Please don't delete my question just ask any question that can help you help me.

Comment: Why not use a model form? Your use case is exactly what they're for. Also for your `posted` field it would be better to just use `posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)`

Answer (score 1):

in your forms.py

try

```
from .models import Blog

class postForm(forms.Form):
   title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
   slug = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
   post_pic = forms.ImageField()
   body = forms.CharField(widget=SummernoteWidget())



   class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ('title', 'slug', 'post_pic', 'body')
```

PS. Iam new to Django, i hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need to save the form, but you're creating a new `Blog` object with values that we can't see defined anywhere.

`new_post = Blog(title=title,slug=slug,post_pic=post_pic,body=body)`

`title`, `slug`, etc don't get defined.

What you should do, is change it to a `ModelForm` so that django does all the hard work;

```py
class postForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ('title', 'slug', 'post_pic', 'body')
        widgets = {
            'body': SummernoteWidget(),
        }
```

Then in your view you just need to do;

```py
    def write_detail(request):
        template_name = 'blog/write.html'
        
        if request.method == 'POST':

            post_form = postForm(request.POST)
            
            if post_form.is_valid():
                post_form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(blog.get_absolute_url()) 
        else:
            # GET request
            post_form = postForm()
     
        return render(request, template_name, {'post_form': post_form})
```

The summernote docs for forms (and modelforms) is [here](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote#form)

Don't forget, that when using a widget like this that comes with media, you need to add the form's media to the template.

You can access it in the HTML using either `{{ form.media }}` to get all CSS and JS, or individually as `{{ form.media.js }}` and `{{ form.media.css }}`

You can see how they do it in the summernote app [playground](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote/blob/master/djs_playground/templates/index.html)

Comment: The reason I'm not using the model form is that I'm using Django summer note: a WYSIWYG editor so it makes it such that I can't use a model form and the editor together.

Comment: @adstefnum That's not true. You can use a text editor like that with a `ModelForm`. It's in their docs. I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just found out somewhere else and didn't recheck your code before posting my answer

Comment: @adstefnum You shouldn't include the JS/CSS like you've suggested. You should get these from the widget itself. I've added an example of this in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```py
class postForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ('title', 'slug', 'post_pic','body')
        widgets = {
            'body':SummernoteWidget(),
        }
```

Sorry guys you can actually use django summer note with a model form. I used it before but the editor was not appearing so I changed it to the one I previously posted but after reading another answer on stack overflow. I found out that I didn't add this code below to my HTML files or just inside my base.html

```html
<!-- include summernote css/js-->
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.3/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.3/summernote.js"></script>
```

Thanks guys